# Django: I want to track from which url a request was made?

Tags: python, reactjs, django

in the TestQuestionList class, the get function must receive an id to return id, I thought that I could do this with the help of `request.get_full_path()`example on the bottom

```
def index2(request, test_id):
    print(request.get_full_path()) #here it works
    return render(request, 'index.html')

class TestQuestionList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        obj = Test.objects.get(id = request.get_full_path())#doesn't work here
        romms = TestQuestionBlok.objects.filter(id__in=obj.questions)
        serializer = TestQuestionSerializers(romms, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

but `request.get_full_path()` instead of
`/tests/api/` (where the request was made from)
returned
`/api/question/`
why?

This is part of the code from where the request was made

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/',
    }).then(response => {
        setAllQuestions(response.data)
    })
}, [])
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('api/tests/', TestList.as_view()),
    path('test/<int:test_id>/', index2),
    path('api/questions/', TestQuestionList.as_view()),
]
```

Thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: First of all, it would be very helpful if you could add `urls.py` code here, too. Secondly, normally, you can get path parameters by just setting the `get` method signature as `def get(self, request, pk)` and then using the `pk` argument. The superclasses pass this when calling get method. So, I suggest trying that. Inspecting the URL for this is something that DRF should handle already for you, so doing it yourself is not the way to go IMO.

Comment: @vinkomlacic added url and tried to add pk but i got error from pk `TypeError: TestQuestionList.get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk' `

Comment: Okay, but you're not passing `pk` in `api/questions` URL. From your question, I assumed that this has to be passed in the URL. E.g. `api/questions/<int:pk`

Comment: @vinkomlacic I do not understand you

Comment: @vinkomlacic i just need to get the url from where the request was made

Comment: @vinkomlacic I updated the question again, please check it again

Comment: What do you mean from where? According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path), `get_full_path` always returns the path (URL) which is mapped to your view + query params. So, according to your `urls.py`, it should be `api/questions`. Also, you cannot pass URL as the value of the ID. This should be an integer.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you very much, it helped me, if it's not difficult, can you add your answer? I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @vinkomlacic I already found the answer `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')`